# Searching Operational Attributes using ldapjs

Tags: node.js, openldap, user-accounts, ldapjs

**Question:**

**How do I search for operational attributes associated with users using ldapjs?**

I know that when using ldapsearch I can get the operational attributes with the '+' argument. I am familiar with ldapjs's client search function, but I do not know how to search for operational attributes with this function.

- Is it possible to search for operational attributes with ldapjs?
- If it isn't a way to search for them, are there any recommendations for other javascript ldap libraries?

**Background**

I have an openldap server running that has a directory laid out like this:

```
-> Root stuff
  -> dc=example,dc=com
    -> cn=Manager (The olcRootDN)
    -> ou=User
       -> *Several entries with objectClasses {posixAccount, shadowAccount, inetOrgPerson}*
    -> ou=Policies
       -> *pwdPolicy with some default password policies
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `+` syntax is part of the LDAP protocol, not part of `ldapsearch`. It works via Java/JNDI for example too.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to pass the '+' argument into ldapjs's client search() function?

Comment: I don't know anything about ldapjs, but the `"+"` goes wherever you specify a list of attributes to return, as a kind of attribute name.